# Chainsaws in Die2nite

Tags: die2nite

How do I make a chainsaw in Die2Nite? Or is it something that I have to pick up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to find the incomplete chainsaw.  Then you also have to find an incomplete engine and build that.  Then you combine the two.  The net cost is 2 nuts & bolts plus a handful of other items, which is hard for a lot of people to swallow for a simple weapon.  But man does it rip through zombies.  Each attack kills 3 zombies, and you need to feed it a new battery about 1 in 3 attacks.  Best of all, after you've spent the batteries, your inventory is now free to carry back items.